# Negative volitional+と

Tags: grammar, particle-と, volitional-form

> 「それじゃあ放課後、茶道室に来て下さい。
> そこでこれからのことを話し合いましょう」
>
> 先輩は校舎のほうへ走っていく。
> それに遅れ**まいと**、こっちも校舎へと走り出した。

Why is the negative volitional used in the last sentence?

Comment: Already solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Construction and meaning

You might have already encountered the positive volitional + と: this indicates something that the subject is *trying to do*, such as 店{みせ}に行{い}**こうと**する: *to try to go* to the store.  The final verb is what is happening, and the volitional verb before it is a kind of dependent hoped-for result: "*suru* **so as to** *iku* to the store".

The positive form of your example above would be: 遅{おく}れ**ようと**…走り出した: "[I] ran off *to try to be later* [than my sempai]" → "[I] ran off *so I would be later* [than my sempai]".

From this construction, we simply change it to the negative form: 遅れ**まいと**…走り出した: "[I] ran off *to try to not be later* [than my sempai]" → "[I] ran off *so I wouldn't [get there] later* [than my sempai]".

This construction using the negative volitional + と appears to be less common and it might be somewhat old-fashioned.  In everyday usage, I'm more accustomed to seeing negative + ように, such as 遅れ**ないように**…走り出した.  A few Google searches broadly corroborate this general impression, but a native speaker could give more definitive feedback.

### Derivation

The -まい negative volitional ending most likely comes from the classical volitional / presumptive ending -む.  Modern -まい grew out of classical -まじ that conjugated almost like a classical *-shi/-ki* adjective (modern *-i* adjective).  This -まじ appears to be a compound of ま (the 未然形{みぜんけい} "irrealis or incomplete form" of む) + じ, an alternative negative volitional / presumptive ending (appearing in the [*Man'yōshū*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB) and [*The Tale of Genji*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_Genji), among other older works).  However, the conjugation similar to a *-shi/-ki* adjective suggests some influence from adjectivizing suffix じ, which Shogakukan describes as attaching to nouns and indicating "that kind of quality".

#### More history - the modern volitional

Note that the classical volitional / presumptive ending -む evolved into the modern volitional.  For regular 五段{ごだん}活用{かつよう} ("five-step conjugation", i.e. type 1) verbs where the ending changes, the -む suffix attaches to the 未然形{みぜんけい} ("irrealis or incomplete form"), the stem form ending in *-a*, resulting in *-amu*.  Over time, the *-mu* suffix lost the "m" sound to become just *-u*, with the combination becoming *-au*.  This diphthong then shifted into a long "o" sound, resulting in the modern volitional ending.

For the simpler 一段{いちだん}活用{かつよう} ("one-step conjugation", i.e. type 2) verbs, the derivation is a little more complicated.  Here too, the -む suffix attaches to the 未然形{みぜんけい} ("irrealis or incomplete form"), but the *mizenkei* for these verbs ends in either *-i* or *-e* -- the same stem ending for all forms.  As the *-mu* suffix lost its "m", the resulting *-imu* or *-emu*  endings become *-iu* or *-eu*.  These diphthongs similarly shifted, producing a contracted *-yō*, such as in classical 上{あ}ぎょう or 見{み}ょう.  That contracted *-yō* was then reanalyzed as a non-contracted suffix on its own, and was then added back onto the *mizenkei* stem of *-i* or *-e*, producing the modern *-iyō* and *-eyō* endings.